# Can I delay evaluation of bool variables in C++?

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
if (ptr == nullptr || really long conditional that depends on ptr existing || another really long conditional)
    // do stuff
```

Due to how C++ evaluates conditionals, I consider this elegant and great, except for the fact that there are really long conditionals involved. The style guide that I follow suggests I break up this statement in `const bool`s like the following:

```
const bool a = really long conditional that depends on ptr not being nullptr
const bool b = another one

if (ptr == nullptr || a || b)
   // do stuff
```

Now this is obviously going to throw an exception when `ptr` is `nullptr`. So to escape this scenario I'd maybe write something like this.

```
if (ptr == nullptr)
    // do stuff
const bool a = really long conditional that depends on ptr not being nullptr
const bool b = another one

if (ptr == nullptr || a || b)
   // do stuff
```

Even if we wrap the stuff we're doing in `// do stuff` in a function, we'd still be calling the function twice which is not very elegant.

What are my options here? Can I delay the evaluation of these const bool variables? Do I `define` and `undef` them? Or do we consider this an edge case that should be handled like the first piece of code in this post?

Comment: `const bool a = ptr && really long conditional that depends on ptr not being nullptr;` and `const bool b = ptr && another one;`

Comment: You can make `a` and `b` to be lambdas. They will be executed when called: `if (ptr == nullptr || a() || b())`.

Comment: *we'd still be calling the function twice* There's no function being called, so you're not even calling a function once. `if (ptr == nullptr)` is not a function call. It's a simple boolean test. It's no more a function call than `if (1==1)` would be.

Comment: So the style guide is telling you to do something infeasible. So ignore it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it, if you *really* want to do it that way. It only evaluates the conditionals for the cases where they're used, setting them to `false` otherwise:

```
const bool a = (ptr == nullptr) ? false : really long conditional ...
const bool b = (ptr == nullptr || !a) ? false : another one;
```

However, since this is *primarily* a code formatting issue at heart, I'd suggest you just do something like (easily readable, in my opinion):

```
if (ptr == nullptr ||
    really long conditional that depends on ptr existing ||
    another really long conditional)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

This removes the need for temporary variables and the more complex evaluation/use of them, and nothing in the standard states that `if` statements need to be on a single line :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
if ( ptr == nullptr || cond1(ptr) || cond2(ptr) )
{
```

where `cond1` and `cond2` could be free functions or lambdas that perform the "really long conditional" test and have meaningful names.